# What does the formula for viscosity have to do with derivatives?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, differentiation, flow, viscosity

The formula for viscosity is given by :$$A\eta \frac{dv}{dx}$$

Where x here is the distance above the surface. In most of the problems I have solved I use the formula like this$$A\eta \frac{v}{x}$$
And I just substitute the value for velocity and displacement when required.
But this is not the actual formula.

What is the role of derivatives and under what circumstances should I use calculus instead of directly substituting values

Comment: The equation you gave is for shear force.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first expression for the shear viscosity is more general. On a high level, viscosity is a property of liquid, which tends to diminish the difference of velocity in the neighboring layers of water. In the leading order in the derivative expansion:
$$
A \eta \frac{\partial v}{\partial x_i}
$$
The expression below in valid only in case, where $v$ depends linearly on $x$ :
$$
v = \alpha x 
$$

Comment: $\frac{dv}{dx}=\frac{v}{x}$ would also require that $\beta=0$ in your expression, so the validity is even more restricted.

Comment: @J.Murray my bad. Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: Beta being 0 doesn't seem like an overly restrictive condition, it implies velocity is zero on the surface. Since this is tagged fluid dynamics, that's consistent with the no-slip behavior that almost always happens in fluid flows.